# backbone.js + jScrollPane: keep scrollpane on re-render?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jscrollpane

http://tinkerbin.com/pla4NzJ9

I've created a tiny demo, where a backbone view is instantiated and using `this.$el.jScrollPane()`, a `jScrollPane` is attached to it.

When I re-render the view 5 seconds later, the `jScrollPane` disappears. Anyone know why?

Here I've duplicated the js:

```
var ScrollableView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },

  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(_.template($('#scrollable_template').html(), {})); 
    this.$el.jScrollPane();
    return this;
  }
});

$(function () {
  var scrollableView = new ScrollableView({ el: $('#scrollable') });
  setTimeout(function() {
    scrollableView.render();
    console.log("re-rendered");
  }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin does this when you call `this.$el.jScrollPane()`:

```
return this.each(
    function()  
    {
        var elem = $(this), jspApi = elem.data('jsp'); 
        if (jspApi) {
            jspApi.reinitialise(settings); 
        } else {
            jspApi = new JScrollPane(elem, settings); 
            elem.data('jsp', jspApi);  
        }
    }   
);
```

Take note of the `elem.data('jsp')` check, that means that `.jScrollPane()` does something different the second time you call it on an element.

When you do this:

```
this.$el.html(_.template($('#scrollable_template').html(), {}));
```

Your killing off all the extra elements and event handlers that the first `.jScrollPane()` call added. Then you call `.jScrollPane()` again, it sees that `.data('jsp')` is there, so it probably assumes that everything is already there and doesn't set things up properly.

There is a [`destroy`](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html#destroy) method in the jScrollPane API but I can't get it to work. Manually removing the `jsp` data does seem to work though:

```
render: function () {
  this.$el.removeData('jsp');
  this.$el.html(_.template($('#scrollable_template').html(), {})); 
  this.$el.jScrollPane();
  return this;
}
```

but I honestly don't know if that's going to do something nasty; I'd mess around with it more and try to get `destroy` working before doing `removeDate('jsp')` out of desperation.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this obscure question. `removeData('jsp')` does, as you say, work, and I can't get `destroy` to work properly either. Even if I re-instantiate the scroll pane multiple times, there isn't too much weirdness around the interaction, so I'll use your trick.

Comment: @ash: The [destroy demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/destroy.html) works but I couldn't make it work in your tinkerbin example. Are you using an older version of jScrollPane?

Comment: I'm using http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js, which is the version used on the demo page (and listed for download on the website). Weird, huh?

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate the `jscollpane` on the `initialize()` method of backbone view and in `render()` method use `reinitialze()` method of `jscrollpane`.

Comment: This is logical but doesn't work -- which is why I'm resorting to worse methods.

Answer (score 0):

I was using this for a MarionetteJS CollectionView that was being rendered in a region of my Layout, and initially ran into difficulties similar to what the original question had.

Based on some of the notes in here, I was able to get this working for the CollectionView and not just an individual ItemView.  Here's it is:

```
// On the first render, apply the scrollers.
PlaylistTracks.on( 'show', function() {
$( '.ap-track-list' ).jScrollPane();    
});

// For when it's updated (this app includes paging, so this is frequent)
PlaylistTracks.on( 'render', function() {
    $( '.ap-track-list' ).jScrollPane();    
});

// .destroy() was also buggy for me, actually destroying the view. Use this
// Use removeData instead and manually remove elements for scroller
PlaylistTracks.on( 'before:render', function() {
    PlaylistTracks.$el.removeData('jsp').removeClass( 'jspScrollable' );
    PlaylistTracks.$('.jspContainer').remove();
});
```

And now it's working without any difficulties.  Hope this helps if anyone looks for this again :)